# Comma Separated Foreign Keys

Tags: mysql, sql

```
id                   name             role              test    

------             --------         --------           --------
1                   Name 1           Role 1             1,2     
2                   Name 10          Role 10            3       
3                   Name 100         Role 100           4       
4                   Name 11          Role 11            5,6 


SET @val_find := '';

SELECT  @val_find := test FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`role`= 'role 11';

SELECT @val_find AS test;
```

generates the following output: 5,6

It's working fine when I write:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IN (5,6)
```

Why doesn't it work in this scenario?

```
    SET @val_find := '';

    SELECT  @val_find := test FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`role`= 'role 11';

    SELECT @val_find AS test;

    SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IN (SELECT @val_find)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very common problem.  You should fix your data layout, so you are not storing lists of ids in comma separated lists.  Comma separated lists are bad enough, but storing numeric ids as strings makes it even worse.

If you are stuck with this data structure because you cannot change it, first promise that when you are in control of a database, you won't do such things.  Then, use `find_in_set()`:

```
where find_in_set(id, @val_find) > 0;
```

Comment: thanks @Gordon Linoff its working fine but i just wanted to know that why it didn`t work in that scenario?, do u have any idea? while its result is similar to the result required for searching (5,6)

Comment: Because your query is `users.id IN ('5,6')` which is the same as `users.id = '5,6'`.